# WordPress uploads directory. Featured Images storage

Tags: customization, post-thumbnails, uploads

WordPress stores all uploads in:

***/uploads/year/month/***

I want to store featured images of my custom post type like:

***/uploads/myCustomPostType/***

No date subdirectories etc. I want all the files to be EXACTLY in the same directory.

Also I'd like to have these files resized before placed in the folder(I guess `set_post_thumbnail_size()` will be good enough).

Is it possible?

**[edit]**

If you wonder why I'm asking for that - the answer is Piecemaker I (I don't like the latest version). I want it to display images from **Slider** custom post type automatically and unluckily Piecemaker takes two arguments - filename (different for every file) and file directory (the same in all cases, so images added in different months won't be displayed together).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I figured out I'm able to get exact address of these files using to use get_post_thumbnail_id(), wp_get_attachment_url(), wp_get_attachment_thumb_file(), wp_get_attachment_image_src() within piecemakersXML file.